# Why is my model not recognised?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, razor, enums

I am having trouble understand what my problem is.

I have a model "Vehicle" which has 2 properties that are Enum's.
In my View i am trying to to use a `Html.EnumDropDownListFor`.

My model is this:

```
 public class VehicleModels
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Naam { get; set; }
        public virtual Merken Merk { get; set; }
        public virtual Brandstoffen Brandstof { get; set; }
        public virtual string Kleur { get; set; }
        public virtual string TypeVanMerk { get; set; }
        public virtual string TypeVanTransmissie { get; set; }
        public virtual int Kilometerstand { get; set; }
        public virtual int Bouwjaar { get; set; }
        public virtual int AantalDeuren { get; set; }
        public virtual int Prijs { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Optie> Options { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Foto> Fotos { get; set; }

        public VehicleModels()
        {

        }

    }
```

My Enum's :

```
public virtual Merken Merk { get; set; }
public virtual Brandstoffen Brandstof { get; set; }
```

--

```
public enum Merken
    {
        [Display(Name="Alfa Romeo")]
        AlfaRomeo,
        Audi,
        Bentley,
        BMW,
        Chevrolet,
        Citroën,
        Chrystler,
        Dacia,
        Fiat,
        Ford,
        Honda,
        Hyundai,
        Kia,
        Lexus,
        Mazda,
        Mercedes,
        Mitsubishi,
        Nissan,
        Opel,
        Peugot,
        Renault = 20,
        Seat,
        Skoda,
        Toyata,
        Volkswagen,
        Volvo,
        [Display(Name ="Overige merken")]
        Overige
    }
```

In my View i have this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Cvo.Eindwerk.KevinVanKerrebroeck.Models.VehicleModels>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div id="filterbar">
    <div class="filterBarComponent">
        <div class="dropdownContainer">
            @Html.DropDownList("Merk", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Merken))), "--Kies Merk")          
        </div>
        <div class="dropdownContainer">
            @Html.DropDownList("Brandstof", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Brandstoffen))), "--Kies Brandstof")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filterBarComponent">
        <div>
            <label for="sliderPrijs">Maximum Prijs</label>
            <input id="sliderPrijs" type="range" 
                   min="100" max="50000" 
                   step="100" value="25000" 
                   oninput="outputUpdatePrijs(value)">
            <output for="sliderPrijs" id="prijs">25000</output>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="sliderKm">Kilometer Stand</label>
            <input id="sliderKm" type="range" 
                   min="0" max="500000" 
                   step="10000" value="500000" 
                   oninput="outputUpdateKilometers(value)">
            <output for="SliderKm" id="kmStand">500000</output>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But i would like to use `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Merk , "--Kies merk")`
But it seems like my View does not recognise my model's properties.
Intellisense does not show me any properties and when i do type them i get the error:

> CS1061: 'IEnumerable<VehicleModels>' does not contain a definition for 'Opties' and no extension method 'Opties' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<VehicleModels>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Yet in the Details view i am able to do this and it shows up like i expect it too.

My Details View:

```
@model Cvo.Eindwerk.KevinVanKerrebroeck.Models.VehicleModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}



<div id="detailsPage">
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Merk)
    <h2 id="detailsTitle">Details voor @Model.Merk  @Model.TypeVanMerk</h2>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
```

Why is this working in my Details View but not in my Index View?

Comment: You model is `@model IEnumerable<VehicleModels>` and `IEnumerable<T>` does not contain any properties. You would need a `for` loop (the model will need to be `IList`) or a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `VehicleModels` to generate a dropdownlist for each `VehicleModels` in your collection

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thx, i had a suspicion about that. But i don't want to show each VehicleModel in my collection, i want to show each value in my Enum Class inside that `EnumDropDownListFor`

Comment: Then why is you model a collection of `VehicleModels` if you do not want to show details of your collection? Bit hard to understand what your trying to do.

Comment: @StephenMuecke The complete View has all the `VehicleModels`, thats why its a collection. The part i am struggling on atm is a filter bar at the top of that page.

Comment: In that case you should make your question a bit clearer. The model in your view should be a view model containing 2 properties - `IEnumerable<VehicleModels> Vehicles` (for the loop) and `VehicleModel Filter` (for generating the dropdowns to filter your results). Note the collection property may not even be required if your not initially display any results.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I know my question is very vague, as i said i was having trouble understanding what exactly my problem was. I am generating initial displays atm. Your solution sounds simple enough, i'll give this a try, altho i am not familiar with the concept